# JavaScript: Rearrange an array in order – largest, smallest, 2nd largest, 2nd smallest, 3rd largest, 3rd smallest,

Tags: javascript

Given an array of integers, where the values should be sorted in the following order:
if we have an array

```
[1, -1, -3, 9, -2, -5, 4, 8,]
```

we must rearrange it this way: largest number, smallest number, 2nd largest number, 2nd smallest number, ...

```
[9, -5, 8, -3,  4, -2, 1, -1 ]
```

I get the first largest and smallest numbers, but can't figure out how to make it dynamic for all values in the array.

I know that I must take two variables, say **firstSmallest** and **firstLargest** and point them to the first and last index of the array respectively, run a loop, which I do already in the code below,  and store value into new array by incrementing **firstSmallest** and decrementing **firstLargest**, but couldn't implement into code.

```
let unsortedArr = [1, 5, 8 , 7, 6, -1, -5, 4, 9, 5]

let output = [];

function meanderArray(unsorted){
  let sorted = unsorted.sort((a, b) => a-b);
  let firstSmallest = sorted[0];
  let firstLargest = sorted[unsorted.length-1];

  for(let i = 0; i <= sorted.length; i++){
  //I should increment firstSmallest and decrement firstLargest numbers and store in output
  } 
 return output;
}
meanderArray(unsortedArr);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a toggle object which takes the property of either the first item or last from an array and iterate until no more items are available.

```js
function meanderArray([...array]) {
    const 
        result = [],
        toggle = { shift: 'pop', pop: 'shift' };

    let fn = 'shift';

    array.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    while (array.length) result.push(array[fn = toggle[fn]]());

    return result;
}


console.log(...meanderArray([1, 5, 8, 7, 6, -1, -5, 4, 9, 5]));
```

Comment: I'm confused, what's the point of `([...array])`? Why not simply `(array)`? (genuine question)

Comment: it takes directly a copy of the array without mutating the given data.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array by descending, then logic is the following: take first from start and first from end, then second from start-second from end, etc.

```js
let unsortedArr = [1, 5, 8 , 7, 6, -1, -5, 4, 9, 5]

let output = [];

function meanderArray(unsorted){
  let sorted = unsorted.sort((a, b) => b-a);
  let output = []

  for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length/2; i++){
    output.push(sorted[i])
    if(i !== sorted.length - 1 - i){
      output.push(sorted[sorted.length - 1 - i])
    }
  } 
 return output;
}
let result = meanderArray(unsortedArr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort, then loop and extract the last number with pop() and extract the first number with shift().

```js
let unsortedArr = [1, -1, -3, 9, -2, -5, 4, 8,]
let output = [];

function meanderArray(unsorted){
    let sorted = unsorted.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    for(let i = 0; i < unsortedArr.length + 2; i++){
        output.push(sorted.pop());
        output.push(sorted.shift());
    } 
console.log(output);
return output;
}

meanderArray(unsortedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Fastest Meandering Array method among all solutions mentioned above.***

According to the [JSBench.me](https://jsbench.me/), this solution is the fastest and for your reference i have attached a screenshot below.

I got a different approach, but i found that was very close to one of above answers from **elvira.genkel**.

In my solution for **Meandering Array**, First I sorted the given array and then i tried to find the middle of the array. After that i divided sorted array in to two arrays, which are indices *from 0 to middle index* and other one is *from middle index to full length of sorted array*.

We need to make sure that first half of array's length is greater than the second array. Other wise when applying `for()` loop as next step newly created array will contains some *undefined values*. For avoiding this issue i have *incremented first array length by one*.

So, always it should be **firstArr.length > secondArr.length**.

And planned to create new array with values in meandering order. As next step I created `for()` loop and try to push values from beginning of the first array and from end of the second array. Make sure that dynamically created index of second array will *receive only zero or positive index*. Other wise you can find undefined values inside newly created **Meandering Array**.

***Hope this solution will be helpful for everyone, who loves to do high performance coding :)***

Your comments and suggestions are welcome.

```
const unsorted = [1, 5, 8, 7, 6, -1, -5, 4, 9, 5];
const sorted = unsorted.sort((a,b)=>a-b).reverse();
const half = Math.round(Math.floor(sorted.length/2)) + 1;
const leftArr = sorted.slice(0, half);
const rightArr = sorted.slice(half, sorted.length);
const newArr = [];

for(let i=0; i<leftArr.length; i++) {
 newArr.push(leftArr[i]);
 if (rightArr.length-1-i >= 0) {
   newArr.push(rightArr[rightArr.length-1-i]);
 }
}
```

[image: Reference for JSBench.me perfomance]